# What is this otome game?

Tags: game-identification

I do believe I played this game a very long time ago, and my friend found this image on Twitter, but the name isn't there. I really wanted to play it (again) after all of these years.

This is the only image I got of the game:

[image: image[1]]

Comment: Is the game the image used as someone's avatar, or is that like a player profile in the game?

Comment: @Batophobia It is an avatar, that can be changed on the screen that image was cropped from (hence the "Tap to change").

Answer (score 18):

That is Kiro from [**Mr. Love: Queen's Choice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Love:_Queen%27s_Choice), a "*Chinese female oriented visual novel phone game*":

[image]

Yours is a screenshot from the game's player customisation screen, with a unique ID which is used to be able to add friends (see [here](https://aminoapps.com/c/otome/page/blog/wanna-be-friends-on-mr-love/WNJ5_RdSXuLdX2Bqnq4LNG48wDP7Deblx4) and [here](https://twitter.com/LilSwordMaiden/status/1130555877147258880), for example) but also for [contacting support](https://mrlove.wiki/wiki/Personal_Info).

Comment: I wonder if OP misidentified the screenshot their friend sent them, since that game was only released about a year ago.

Comment: But in mainland China on December 20, 2017. Still, not "very long ago", indeed (depending on one's age, I suppose).